# How can i use entities from symfony2 in another project using only doctrine2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Entities in symfony 2 have doctrine tags that are preceded with @ORM\ (eg @ORM\Entity).

When using doctrine as a component it expects the tags without the ORM (eg @entity).

If i want to use these entities from a symfony project in another project that uses doctrine but without symfony this causes problems.

How can i set up the non symfony project to use these classes with @ORM\ tags?

Comment: are you planning to use another framework different than symfony? if so, which one?

Comment: yes... but it is a legacy custom framework.

Comment: hmm.. i think as long as you have a way of autoloading classes you can make it work... using the new namespaces in php you could put the doctrine library in your framework's "lib" folder, autoload it, and then from your entities you could do something like `use \YourLibs\Doctrine\ORM as ORM` so you don't have to change anythin in your entities... not quite sure though...

Comment: i tried something like that and it didn't work. the command line tool doesn't recognize the attributes

Comment: Have you considered using a different mapping method such as yaml or xml to manage instead of annotation as it may provide a simple alternative to workaround the issue?

Comment: @MadManMonty good point. you can export your current annotation mappings to yaml or xml from the symfony project using doctrine CLI tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment i have gone for the work around suggested by MadManMonty in the comments to me question:

> Have you considered using a different mapping method such as yaml or xml to manage instead of annotation as it may provide a simple alternative to workaround the issue? – MadManMonty

Answer (score 0):

`@ORM\` prefix is not Symfony specific. It's in Doctrine Common docs: http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/common/2.2/en/reference/annotations.html#introduction

You have to register you annotation file(s) with `AnnotationRegistry::registerFile()` as described in the docs. Also, check Symfony's app/autoload.php file. It's registering its autoloader: in the AnnotationRegistry

```
AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader(function($class) use ($loader) {
    $loader->loadClass($class);
    return class_exists($class, false);
});
AnnotationRegistry::registerFile(__DIR__.'/../vendor/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/Driver/DoctrineAnnotations.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working like this by setting $useSimpleAnnotationReader to false in EntityManager::create():

```
// bootstrap.php
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;

//IGNORE IF YOU DONT NEED SERIALIZER/VALIDATOR
AnnotationRegistry::registerAutoloadNamespace('JMS\Serializer\Annotation', $vendorPath . '/jms/serializer/src');
AnnotationRegistry::registerAutoloadNamespace('Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint', $vendorPath . '/symfony/validator');
//IGNORE IF YOU DONT NEED SERIALIZER/VALIDATOR

AnnotationRegistry::registerFile($vendorPath . '/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/Driver/DoctrineAnnotations.php');

$paths = array("/path/to/entities-or-mapping-files");
$isDevMode = false;

// the connection configuration
$dbParams = array(
    'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
    'user'     => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'dbname'   => 'foo',
);

$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($paths, $isDevMode);
//LAST PARAMETER SETS $useSimpleAnnotationReader TO FALSE
$entityManager = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config, null, null, false);
```